# No se observan los iconos de redes sociales html5

Tags: html, css, html5, font-awesome, redes-sociales

Al subir la web al hosting, no aparecen los iconos de redes sociales en el framework de *fontawesome*, para los cual quiero saber por que no se evidencian los iconos de redes sociales en el *footer*:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GeoFault</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo_gf.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

HTML/Footer

```
<div class="texto_footer">
    <h4>Redes sociales</h4>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fa-facebook:hover {
    color:#3B5998;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover{
    color:#0177B5;
}
.fa-whatsapp:hover{
    color:#0177B5;
}
.fa-google-plus:hover {
    color:#0177B5;
}
i.fa::before {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Quiero saber por que no aparecen los iconos en el *footer*.

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador y revisa si existe algún error

Comment: Te recomendaría que mejor descargaras el archivo de fontawesome y lo pongas como local, ya que si se cae algun momento el CDN tendrias problemas.

Por otro lado en este caso podria ser que tu servidor este haciendo restricciones a conexiones externas. Teoricamente te deberia funcionar como lo muestras.

Comment: Ok, voy a tratar de hacerlo de manera local

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste Miguel?

Comment: Estoy viendo un tutorial para hacerlo de forma local. Pero nose si se tendría otra solución o cual seria la mas recomendada.

Comment: Utilicé el fontawesome 4 de forma local, y me resultó. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solucion rapida, solo reemplacé tu `link rel="stylesheet"` con mi `script` anterior a `</head>` y todo debería funcionar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GeoFault</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo_gf.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0adc4d4ec5.js"></script>
  <style>
    i.fa{height:30px; width:30px; font-size:20px}
    .fa-facebook:hover{color:#3B5998}
    .fa-linkedin:hover,.fa-whatsapp:hover,.fa-google-plus:hover{color:#0177B5}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="texto_footer">
  <h4>Redes sociales</h4>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
i.fa{height:30px; width:30px; font-size:20px}
.fa-facebook:hover{color:#3B5998}
.fa-linkedin:hover,.fa-whatsapp:hover,.fa-google-plus:hover{color:#0177B5}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0adc4d4ec5.js"></script>
<div class="texto_footer">
<h4>Redes sociales</h4>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://geofault.com" target="_blank" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

También corregí un poco y simplifiqué el CSS.

G+ ahora está obsoleto...

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)